# implement a callback between two sites - communicating between two sites

Tags: javascript, html, webservice-client

I have a web app in http://domain1/app1/called.html, and I want to embed that application inside http://domain2/app2/caller.html with an iframe (or a popup, it's the same)

the user should be able to interact with called.html, until they press a certain button, in that case I need to tell caller.html that the user selected an item from called.html

I tried implementing it with javascript.

in called.html I encode the data in json, and then I execute a "called_callback" javascript function in caller.html, passing the json as a parameter.

if called.html was called with a popup, I issue window.opener.called_callback( jsonData ), if it's an iframe I just issue parent.called_callback( jsonData )

having caller.html and called.html in the same domain everything works fine, but from different domains I get the following errors:

```
permission denied (on IE6)
```

and

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL [..]/caller.html from frame with URL [...]called.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match. (on google chrome)
```

Is it possible to overcome this limitation?

What other way of achieving it can you think of???

I guess caller.html could implement a web service, and I could send the result calling it, but the page caller.html would have to poll in order to detect any change...

So how can one application communicate with another one in a different domain to signal an event???

Comment: Do you own domain1 and domain2 ?

Comment: yeap, one app is mine, the other is from a team that is working with us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both answer I found the following:

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

> jQuery postMessage enables simple and
>   easy window.postMessage communication
>   in browsers that support it (FF3,
>   Safari 4, IE8), while falling back to
>   a document.location.hash communication
>   method for all other browsers (IE6,
>   IE7, Opera).
>
> With the addition of the
>   window.postMessage method, JavaScript
>   finally has a fantastic means for
>   cross-domain frame communication.
>   Unfortunately, this method isn’t
>   supported in all browsers. One example
>   where this plugin is useful is when a
>   child Iframe needs to tell its parent
>   that its contents have resized.

I'll have a look at it...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) to call resources from one domain to another.

You can use [window.name](http://beebole.com/en/blog/general/sandbox-your-cross-domain-jsonp-to-improve-mashup-security/) as ~2Mb text transfer between cross domain frames for older browser.

Or for modern browser you can use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate string data between the 2 frames.

But you need some cooperation from the domains for these techniques to work.

Comment: `postMessage` isn't limited to string data. The standard allows for various things such as objects and `ImageData` arrays. Also, using `window.name` no longer works in some modern browsers.

Comment: @Eli, Are you sure about the general availability of non string data with `postMessage`? JSON would be great... For `window.name`, it is a hack ;) precisely for older browsers.

Comment: @Eli, Hm, seems there has been some work being done on this since last time I checked, seems now it allows anything that can be cloned http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#structured-clone

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [JSONP](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding).  It is fully supported in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you are using that particular framework.  It allows you to use JSON across domains.

Answer (score 0):

here's a very complete document that analizes the different approaches...

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

another solution to have a look at

http://easyxdm.net/

with a sample

http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/setting-up-your-first-socket/

Comment: My [article on Script Junkie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff800814) has a better explanation of the different approaches - it's based on the internals of easyXDM.